# UUID mapped type using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to have a `UUID` as primary key for an Entity.
I'm using JPA, Spring (with Hibernate and `MySQL` as `DB`)

I used this code to specify the `UUID` as primary key:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "table_id")
private UUID id;
```

I used a file `data.sql` to initialize my DB for testing.

How can I specify the `UUID` values for the `INSERT` queries?

I saw that I can specify the `UUD` type as `char` using an Annotation. In this way It's easy for my `INSERT` queries. But, how can I use these `INSERT` queries if the `UUID` is mapped as `BINARY` type?

Is it the best practice to use `BINARY` instead of `CHARS` for the `UUID`?

Comment: Binary means it will be serialized as a java object (blob). So i highly doubt that is what you want. You probably want a char(36) as the type and convert to char and vice-versa.

Comment: I could answer this by copying the Hibernate docs. But what about starting with reading some documentation? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-uuid

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated UUID type can give you data validation and efficient storing.
It's a good choice to use [uuid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) type for Postgres. If your database doesn't support UUID type, you can try with BYTE or TEXT with check constraint.